# In DropWizard, can we have a default YAML configuration file?

Tags: dropwizard

We are using DropWizard v0.8.1 and we're wondering if we can have a YAML files with default values that will then get overridden by the specific environment file (such as `dev.xml`).

Spring boot works this way, where the `application.yml` file act as a template for default values and then `application-dev.yml` will override duplicate properties.

We don't want to duplicate all the repetitive properties and only want to update in one file the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own ConfigurationProvider that combines 2 InputStreams and use yaml merge directives

Answer (score -1):

You can use a configuration management tool, such as Ansible, to manage your configurations files.

Set up a template .yml file, and substitute the variables per environment as needed.